# Is there a best practice when you want an html heading element's content to be displayed over multiple lines?

Tags: html, css

I know the following HTML is not valid because the `div` inside the `h2` is a block element:

HTML

```
<h2>
    <div>November 23 2015</div>
    <div>This Is My First Blog Post</div>
</h2>
```

I want to know what the best way to get the date and title of this example blog post heading to display on separate lines with valid HTML. I've done the following which I understand is technically valid:

HTML

```
<h2>
    <span>November 23 2015</span>
    <span>This Is My First Blog Post</span>
</h2>
```

CSS

```
span { display: block; }
```

Maybe I'm wrong in thinking the date of this example blog post should be considered part of the heading of the post, and I should just do something like this:

HTML

```
<p>November 23 2015</p>
<h2>This Is My First Blog Post</h2>
```

But assuming there is some case where you'd have a legitimate need for a multi line heading, I'm wondering what the best way to do it is.

EDIT

I should add that I know I can also just add a `<br>` after the first `<span>`, but the issue with that approach is losing control over the vertical spacing between the lines because adjusting the top/bottom margins/padding doesn't work for inline elements.

Comment: IMHO, This question is not about programming!, instead about *User Experience*, So I suggest you to ask this kind of question here: https://ux.stackexchange.com/ ;).

Comment: I think this is more about semantics than User Experience

Comment: If it were still part of the spec, I'd say use [hgroup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hgroup) and a pair of h2 and h3 tags. The example you're showing really should be two separate elements, though.

Comment: I'm looking for HTML/CSS coding options to solve a particular display issue which is my ultimate question, even though I suggest that using separate elements (paragraph and heading) altogether may be the more acceptable approach in my blog post example specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect use-case for the HTML5 `header` element.  It would be semantically correct to use two separate HTML tags - one for the title, and one for the date - as they are two separate entities, and the `header` can contain them both.

```html
<header>
  <h2>This Is My First Blog Post</h2>
  <span>November 23 2015</span>
</header>
```

If you want a multi-line heading, simply for design purposes, then it would be semantically correct to use CSS to achieve it.

```css
h2 {
  width: 230px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<h2>This is a Very Long Title and the Desired Look is to Have it Take Up Less Width</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know if `<header>` is just intended to be used once on a page, mainly at the top of the page with stuff like a logo, navigation and banner, etc.?

Comment: For anyone else reading this, [according to W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element), `<header>` is meant to contain introductory information for a section of content on a page, like multiple blog post for example.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the `<br>` tag is the simplest way, but in most cases it's semantically incorrect.

Comment: Right, I need to edit my question to make the issue I'm having more clear. I tried using the `<br>` element but seem to lose a lot of control over the vertical spacing of the lines because of adjusting margin and padding on inline elements.

Comment: @Kevin `#element-after-br { display: inline-block }`, then those "block" element exclusive CSS rules will be available now. BUT! I'm just answer to your comment, check out other posts, such as use `<hgroup>` for subtitles and `<header>` for dates or etc is the best practice.

Comment: ahh, I guess `inline-block` is another option similar to `block`. Thanks for reminding me about that one! still looking into them but yeah I like the other suggestions so far.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting a `br` tag at the point of the desired linebreak is a straightforward approach, and you can retain control over the vertical spacing of the lines by setting a `line-height` property on the `h2` element.

Comment: Thanks I'll play around with that. I think there might be less control over vertical spacing though since the line height would effect the space above and below both lines equally? What if you want a different spacing above first line line than second line?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="post-title">
    <span class="date">November 23 2015</span>
    <h2 class="heading">This Is My First Blog Post</h2>
</div>
```

:) hope  it helps! Good Luck!